# MySQL stores wrong timestamp

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 6. I have created a ticketing system and successfully uploaded on server.

I am storing ticket creation time in `created_at` field in my MySQL database. The problem is sometimes the timestamp in `created_at` field is correct and sometimes it stores wrong timestamp.

The problem is weird and I cannot figure it out and don't know how to debug this issue.

My timezone in Laravel config/app.php is set to Asia/Kolkata

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
```

Here is my ticket create method

```
$ticket_tracker = TICKET_TRACKER::create
        ([
            'ticket_no' => $ticket_number,
            'partner_id' => $partner_id,
            'team_id'   => $team_id,
            'priority_id'   => $priority_id,
            'opened_date'   => $opened_date,
            'created_by'   => $user_id,
        ]);
```

`created_at` field is not included in above code as Laravel stores time itself.

**Table Structure**

[image]

After further digging into issue I have discovered that MySQL stored correct timestamp when I created a ticket for testing. After few hours I have created the another ticket which is saved with correct timestamp but timestamp of my old ticket changed itself (I don't know how this happened).

Also I found that my global and session time zone is system which is UTC I think because my current time is 5.30 hour ahead of timestamp displayed by this command `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Can we see the table definition?

Comment: I suspect the default timestamp is being generated in the MySQL query, and is using MySQL's configured timezone.

Comment: I have updated the question with table structure

Answer (score 1):

Because you not provide `created_at` & `updated_at` values by you query the values is generated on MySQL side according MySQL server time and timezone.
For check get MySQL current time use next simple query:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not match to your time zone you can change timezone settings following [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Eloquent itself creates values for ```created_at``` and ```updated_at``` with respect to the timezone settings in the app.config file. So that is the correct way by not setting values explicitly.